# Selecting the colnames of the lowest 5 values for every row in a data frame in r

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data frame:

```
df=df=data.frame('var1'=c(1,3,5,7),'var2'=c(4,6,8,10),var3=c(11,12,13,14))
df

  var1 var2 var3
    1    4   11
    3    6   12
    5    8   13
    7   10   14
```

Now I am calculating distance of each row with every other row using var1 & var2

```
library(fields)
df_dist=df_dist=rdist(df[,1:2])
df_dist
         1        2        3        4
1 0.000000 2.828427 5.656854 8.485281
2 2.828427 0.000000 2.828427 5.656854
3 5.656854 2.828427 0.000000 2.828427
4 8.485281 5.656854 2.828427 0.000000
```

Now my objective is to select the two colnames from each row which have lowest values in that row(excluding 0 i.e. distance from itself), so for row1 the output should be colname = 2 & 3, similarly for row2 the output should be 1 & 3 etc.

i am able to do this using for loop but it takes a lot of time for large dataset, is there a better way using apply, lapply etc which can save this time.

The for loop code is as follows:

```
d=as.data.frame(df_dist)
#Setting the column and row names as var3 values
colnames(d)<-df$var3
rownames(d)<-df$var3

#Intitialiazing variable e
e<-NULL


for (i in 1:nrow(d))
{

  tmp=colnames(d)[order(d[i,], decreasing=FALSE)][2:3]  
  e<-rbind(e,tmp)
}

f=as.data.frame(e)

rownames(f)<-df$var3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
df = read.table(text="1        2        3        4
1 0.000000 2.828427 5.656854 8.485281
2 2.828427 0.000000 2.828427 5.656854
3 5.656854 2.828427 0.000000 2.828427
4 8.485281 5.656854 2.828427 0.000000")

t(apply(df,1,function(x) colnames(df)[order(x)[2:3]]  ))
```

OUTPUT:

```
  [,1] [,2]
1 "X2" "X3"
2 "X1" "X3"
3 "X2" "X4"
4 "X3" "X2"
```

So for row4, column X3 contains the lowest value, and X2 the second-lowest.

Hope this helps!